# UIButton setTitle toggle, automatic reload?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have buttons with a bool as toggle. Whenever i change the toggle, I want the title to change. But whenever I change the toggle, the title doesn't automatically change. Can someone tell me how to do it?

code:

```
@interface OrderController ()
{
    std::string currentValue;
    bool buttonToggle;
    NSString *orderNumber;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    buttonToggle = true;
}

- (IBAction)button1:(id)sender
{
    if (buttonToggle)
    {
        [sender setTitle:@"1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        currentValue += "1";
        orderNumber = [NSString stringWithCString:currentValue.c_str() encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    }
    else
    {
        [sender setTitle:@"A" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        orderNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", orderNumber, @"A"];
        buttonToggle = true;
    }
}

- (IBAction)swipeUp:(id)sender
{
    buttonToggle = false;
}
```

Comment: `currentValue` is declared as `int`. How come `currentValue.c_str()` compiles?

Comment: sorry, should be `std::string`

Comment: What's the initial title? Does it change the first time through?

Comment: by toggle do you mean touchUpInside .or touchDown then touchUP.!
when swipe up called ,,and button1 called

Comment: Any reason you're not using a UISwitch?

Comment: by toggle I mean changing the boolean `buttonToggle`. The initial buttontitle is `"1"`. When swipeUp is called, the buttontitle should change to `"A"`. But instead, it only changes whenever I press the button. I need a button because I'm using these buttons to create a string of numbers/letters.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it:

```
- (IBAction)button1:(UIButton *)sender  //line was changed
{
if (buttonToggle)
{
    sender.titleLabel.text=@"1"; //line was changed
    currentValue += "1";
    orderNumber = [NSString stringWithCString:currentValue.c_str() encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
else
{
    sender.titleLabel.text=@"A"; //line was changed
    orderNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", orderNumber, @"A"];
    buttonToggle = true;
}
}
```